# What are the headers to set in the Rest API for the HTTP GET request

Tags: java, python, ajax, django

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def gatewayentities_list(request,format=None):
    requestMeta = request.META
    if ('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in requestMeta.keys()):
        return JSONResponse({"status": "UNAUTHORIZED"}, status=401)
    elif (requestMeta['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] is not None):
        headerParameters = requestMeta['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(" ")
        companyid_id = headerParameters[2]
        apikey = headerParameters[0]
        userId = headerParameters[3]
        try:
            applicationid = int(headerParameters[4])
        except IndexError:
            applicationid = 0
```

> {'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',   'Vary': 'Cookie',   'Server':
>   'Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)',   'Connection': 'close',   'Date': 'Wed, 06
>   Jun 2018 06:50:09 GMT',   'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}

```
Server Error (500)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: looking for curl command to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get not seem to be related to request mapping header.

Your request mapping method should be something like:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "data")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> gatewayentities_list(@ModelAttribute ,BindingResult errors, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
// your code.
}
```